# Compare queries from 2 data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud

I know enough to know that I should be embarrassed to ask this question...

In SFMC I have two basic data extensions - both the result of imports from our CRM.

Data Extension 1 (DE 1) has two fields called "Contact: email" and "Record Type"
Data Extension 2 (DE 2) has a single field called "email"

The destination Data Extension has two fields: "Contact: email" and "Record Type"

What I want the query to do is compare DE 1 against DE 2 and EXCLUDE any contact from DE 1 that is also on DE 2. Kind of an ad hoc suppression list.

Here is the query:

```
 Select [Contact: Email],
 [Record Type]
 From DE 1
 Where [Contact: Email] NOT IN
 (select Email from DE 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what type of error are you getting? Is it providing results, just not what you would expect?

Comment: Hi @UTScreenwright, don't worry about the question you're asking. We all started at some point. Your question is very well formulated and we can see that you have tried to find the solution on your own.

Comment: @Gortonington - no errors...just no results. I did a test of this query and expected to get 2 contacts on my destination Data Extension. The query ran successfully...just no results.

Comment: @MartinLezer - thank you... it drives me nuts though that I'm burning goodwill on [what I think is] a very 101 question. I want my money back on my Udemy class!

Comment: (just kidding Udemy)

Comment: Have you run the query without the NOT IN? verify that the first DE is returning results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the EXISTS operator:

```
Select 
    [Contact: Email],
    [Record Type]
From 
    [DE 1] a
Where
    not exists
     (
        Select 
            Email 
        From 
            [DE 2] b
        Where 
            b.Email = a.[Contact: Email]
     )
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much @Rufenstein.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities : 
-there is a space in your data extension name so you need to add brackets too :
[DE 1] (if it's not a placeholder  name)
-your Email fields are text type and don't have the same length

Comment: I can rule out the spaces in the data extensions name (they are all camel case). But I did have inconsistent data types across DE 1, DE 2 and the destination DE. I'm going to fix that now...

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN and IS NULL. It would take less time to run if you are running the query on a large amount of data.

`SELECT [Contact: Email], [Record Type]
From [DE 1] a
LEFT JOIN [DE 2] b
   ON a.[Contact: Email] = b.Email from DE 2)
WHERE b.Email IS NULL`